# Red Epic, Adobe Premiere Editing Workflow

Tags: premiere, workflow, red

We shot some stuff on a Red Epic. The footage is on a 2TB Hitachi HD. Now I need to edit the footage. I can't transfer all the footage to my MacPro desktop because it is too many TB and will take too long. I also tried editing the footage straight from the external Hitachi HD before and it is very laggy and no good.

So what is the preferred workflow for this situation? I've heard something about exporting proxies or low-res video from the original footage via RedCine-X Pro. Then using that low-res footage to edit in Premiere. Then I guess export some data that will link to the original footage, or name the low-res files the same filenames as the original footage?

I'm lost and need a workflow.

Answer (score 4):

Drag all your r3d files into Adobe Media Encoder (or CineX Pro), transcode to ProRes 422 (Proxy) and then use these to make your edit in Premiere. Once done, make the proxy footage offline in your project window and then relink to the original files.

Make sure to keep your folder structures the same for the proxies so that relinking is just a 1-click process. Also think before about what resolution you're delivering in and use sequence settings to reflect this.

Also make sure you actually have room for the proxies on your desktop. The files will be smaller but still take up a significant amount of space.

Comment: http://www.premiumbeat.com/blog/premiere-pro-quick-tip-how-to-create-proxies/